# Checking free partition space in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

Alright, I have a chron job on my raspberry pi that takes a picture every 15 minutes, and now I want to use my piglow board to indicate how much space is left in the partition that the pictures are stored in.  So I want a python script to check how much space is on the partition and how much is used, then divide the amount used by the total space and light up the LEDs based off of that.  I know how to do everything except get the partition info.

Comment: Have you written any code so far? Maybe post this and we can help you add in the partition info where it needs to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> mnt = commands.getoutput("cat /proc/partitions")
>>> print mnt
major minor  #blocks  name

   3     0   19551168 hda
   3     1    6345675 hda1
   3     2   13205398 hda2
   3    64   19551168 hdb
   3    66          1 hdb2
   3    69     835348 hdb5
   3    70    9767425 hdb6
   3    71     192748 hdb7
   3    72    8755393 hdb8
  34     0   19551168 hdg
  34     1   19542568 hdg1
   8     0     992000 sda
   8     1     991747 sda1



import re
import commands

def get_size(device):
    '''
    Input  : Device name.
    Output : The devices size in 512-byte blocks.
    '''
    return commands.getoutput(
        'cat /sys/class/block/{}/size'.format(
        device))


print get_size('sda1')
```

Comment: You can open and read the file. No need to run the cat command.